# Why include multiple headers for one POSIX function?

Tags: c, posix, standards, header-files

According to the man page `getaddrinfo(3)`, I need to

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
```

to use the function `getaddrinfo`.  Or, according to [the standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getaddrinfo.html):

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
```

I understand I need things like `AF_INET` and `SOCK_STEAM` from `<sys/socket.h>`.  But I still have the following questions.

Suppose I will only use the `getaddrinfo` function, do I have to `#include <sys/socket.h>` to be standard conformant? If so, why doesn't `<netdb.h>` include it itself?  If not, why does the man page include it in the synopsis?

Answer (score 5):

The only header you need to be able to call `getaddrinfo` in a meaningful way is `netdb.h`. An example usage case would be looping over the results and calling `getnameinfo` on each with `NI_NUMERICHOST` in order to print the numeric address(es) a hostname resolves to. This does not require any interfaces outside of `netdb.h`.

However, if you want to restrict your query to a specific address family, you'll need the header that defines the address family constants (`sys/socket.h`). You'll also generally want to use the results to make suitable sockets and open connections, which also needs `sys/socket.h`. Presumably the reason this header is included in the specification is that it's needed for access to *all* (not just *some*) of the functionality `getaddrinfo` provides.

As for `sys/types.h`, that's just cruft in the Linux man page, I think. Generally `sys/types.h` should never be used unless you're in a situation where you just want type definitions *without* pulling in macro constants and function prototypes.

Comment: In old versions of POSIX (those from the last millennium, not this one), `<sys/types.h>` was needed most places.  POSIX 2004 upgraded things so that you seldom or never need to include it specifically any more.  It is 'cruft', but it has a historic reason for being there.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Do you have a citation for that?

Comment: Example: [`getgid()` 1997](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7990989775/xsh/getgid.html); [`getgid()` 2004](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getgid.html).  There probably is verbiage somewhere that specifies it — I've not looked for it recently.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: If you follow your link to the corresponding version of `unistd.h` you'll see that it's required to define `gid_t`. Inclusion of `sys/types.h` in the synopsis seems to just be cruft or to be informative regarding the place where `gid_t` is specified.

Comment: Nominally, the synopsis is what is needed to use the function — the headers listed were nominally needed.  That is certainly how it was interpreted, I believe, by most people.  So, in 1997, nominally you needed both `<sys/types.h>` and `<unistd.h>` — that's what the 1997 synopsis said.  There might be other, better examples to choose than `getgid()`, of course; it was the first I happened to come across in a semi-random selection of functions to check — and I was mildly surprised to find it had the `<sys/types.h>` in 1997.

Comment: Also, if you look at the tail end of the 2004 page, under changes, you find information: **Issue 6** _In the SYNOPSIS, the optional include of the `<sys/types.h>` header is removed. —— The following new requirements on POSIX implementations derive from alignment with the Single UNIX Specification: • The requirement to include` <sys/types.h>` has been removed. Although `<sys/types.h>` was required for conforming implementations of previous POSIX specifications, it was not required for UNIX applications._ The information also appears in the 2008/2013 version of the `getgid()` specification, too.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Interesting. The text you quoted does not even make sense though: "Although <sys/types.h> was required for conforming *implementations*..." - the topic at hand is requirements on applications, not implementations.

Comment: BTW as I understand it SUSv2 is not a source for any version of POSIX; prior to SUSv3, POSIX and SUS were maintained separately and not aligned. So I think to say anything about whether earlier POSIX had an actual requirement on applications to do this, or just contradictory nonsense, would require actually digging up the standard, which doesn't seem to be publicly available.

Comment: I think it means that for a POSIX application to conform to a conforming POSIX implementation's requirements, it had to include `<sys/types.h>`, even though the historical UNIX implementations did not require it, and the 2004 POSIX standard removed the need to include `<sys/types.h>` for compatibility with Unix systems. If you find the right section to read (I haven't yet), there's almost certainly more information about the change elsewhere.

Comment: I do think I've identified that there was a change along the lines mentioned in my first comment, and that I've provided material that shows I am not wholly making it up as I go. And I think I've shown that the mention of `<sys/types.h>` in the Linux man pages is mostly a (crufty) historical relic that might once have been necessary but isn't any more.